# vscode ubuntu asp .net core 3.1 service immediately exits with code 0 when api request is called

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

when debugging in vscode in ubuntu asp.net core 3.1 service, this service is started and listening on ip:port. Problem is that if I send api request on that ip:port, service immediately exits with code 0.

```
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: /home/name/project
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5020
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

The program '[11834] WebService.dll' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

If service is run using dotnet run command, this issue is not present, however I am not able to debug.

Can you please look at my launch.json and task.json, whether there is any problem?

launch.json

```
        {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [         
            {
                "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
                "type": "coreclr",
                "request": "launch",
                "preLaunchTask": "build",
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/path/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/WebService.dll",
                "args": ["--urls","http://0.0.0.0:5020"],
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "console": "internalConsole",
                "env": {
                    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
                },
            },      
            {
                "name": ".NET Core Attach",
                "type": "coreclr",
                "request": "attach",
                "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
            }
        ]
    }
```

task.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",               
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: In my case problem was in AspNetZero. i needed license